# Camel retry processing in a inner route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I was trying to implement a retry mechanism with inner routes in camel DSL with spring.
For example I have the following two routes:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <to uri="procA"/>
    <to uri="direct:sub"/>
    <to uri="procB"/>
</route> 
<route >
    <from uri="direct:sub"/>
    <to uri="procD"/>
    <process ref="myProcessor"/>
</route>
```

and I want to achieve the following behaviour: when there is an error in the first route or in the second route I want that the operation with the error (and not the entire route) is retried, in addition the sub-route could be called also by others routes in which the retried mechanism is not allowed. In other words the retry mechanism shoud be controlled by the main route.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: yes, see https://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html